# WPF app failing on some machines

Tags: .net, wpf

I have 2 machines with win 7 64 bit SP1 and I just ran into this [bug](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/931d7bff-90b6-4a70-bb0b-3a097e1301a1/net-40-breaking-change-using-a-markup-extension-as-value-of-property-setter-in-xaml-style?forum=wpf) on one of these two. Both are up to date and the only difference i see is that the failing machine has WPF-dll files with fileversion 4.0.30319.1015 and the running fine has 4.0.30319.18060.

How to fix the failing machine?

Of course i already tried:

- update windows -> check
- update .NET framework

  - NDP40-KB2468871-v2-x64.exe -> check
  - NDP40-KB2840628-v2-x64.exe -> check
  - NDP40-KB2600211-x86-x64.exe -> check
  - NDP45-KB2840642-v2-x64.exe -> starts with "does not apply"

but the app still won't run and the fileversion in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319 has not changed.

Edit:

Reinstalling is not an option for now because the manager is hesitant to touch his running system. However installing the WPF-App (effectivly moving it to Program Files) did solve the problem even if the files under C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319 have not changed.

Comment: Okay, you did the basics.  What about uninstalling 4.0, then installing 4.51?

Comment: @Will that's what i would like to avoid because it is a manager pc and breaking this will result in a lot of trouble. Also how to handle this on client machines? I hoped for the "use this link" kind of answer

Comment: You wanted a link?  :| (reaches for *Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow...*)

Answer (score 1):

Am I missing something here? Have you tried to update the machine you are having trouble with to `4.0.30319.18060` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be an issue with Client profile of DotNet Framework you might be having client on the falling machine. If not you can unistall and reInstall the [DotNet framework 4.0](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=17718)